# setting up unique constraint on referenced columns in oracle 10g xe

Tags: oracle, constraints, unique

I have the following situation.

table looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE CompetitionsLanguages (
  competition REF CompetitionType SCOPE IS Competitions,
  language REF LanguageType SCOPE IS Languages
);
```

I need this table to have a unique constraint on (competition,language) combination.
oracle tells me that i cant put a UNIQUE or PK on columns that reference other tables.

is it possible to somehow avoid the unique, using the CHECK, or some sort of a TRIGGER?

Comment: I don't know the answer.  But out of curiosity, why are you using this object syntax in your tables?  I can assure you that the number of real world database built on this kind of syntax is (as good as) zero!

Comment: jusing them for an example project in college course. dont ask me wyh, i would never voluntarily to this. but, as it is, it is. so i have to come up with some sort of a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unqIndex
    ON CompetitionsLanguages(CompetitionsLanguages, CompetitionsLanguages);
```

Comment: +1 Interesting that this works when creating a UNIQUE CONSTRAINT fails with ORA-02329.